# Склонение слов "горничная", "фамилия" и "учительство", "метро"

Tags: грамматика

Почему данные пары слов(каждая пара в отдельности) не относятся к одному склонению ?
1. Горничная, фамилия
2. Учительство, метро

Comment: Вас интересует, именно "почему"? Язык у нас так устроен...))) Потому, что относятся к разным. К каким именно - Vera ответила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Горничная - склоняется как прилагательное в форме ж.р. ед. числа. Это прилагательное (схема образования: горница - горничная), перешедшее в существительное.

Фамилия -  существительное 1-го склонения (ж.р., с основой на А/Я).

2. Учительство -  существительное 2-го склонения (ср.род).

Метро - несклоняемое существительное.